# C++ container types facing an issue like conversion from map<long unsigned int, ..> to non scalar type map<short unsigned int, ..>

Tags: c++, json

```
  std::map<uint16_t, std::u16string> val = layoutJson["MapUInt64String16VectFloat64ReqProvOp"]["value"];

  // string16 to string conversion
  std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<char16_t>, char16_t> convertor;
  std::string actualData = convertor.to_bytes(val.begin()->second);

//ERROR
  std::map<uint16_t, std::u16string> receivedData = operationMapUInt64String16VectFloat.GetResult();

  CK_EQ(actualData, convertor.to_bytes(receivedData.begin()->second));
```

I already tried so many ways to resolve this issue and the where I declared the data types all are same. Still i am getting the issue

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: Could you please reorganize a bit your question? This will benefit you as well, if others can understand your problem. e.g. add a code snippet, and clarify better the compiler errors u get..

Comment: The error just means "map<A,B> can't be converted to a map<X,Y>". What is your question's relation to JSON, BTW?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to assign one map to another directly, they can't have different key and value types:

```cpp
std::map<uint64_t, std::u16string> input;
std::map<uint16_t, std::string> output = input; // error, key and value types are different
```

Instead, you have to do one of two options:

1. just use the existing map type in `layoutJson`. This is the best option, since there's less overhead and fewer corner cases like "what happens if the key doesn't fit in a uint16_t?". You can use `auto` to avoid looking up and  typing long type names:

   ```cpp
   auto output = layoutJson["MapUInt64String16VectFloat64ReqProvOp"]["value"];
   ```
2. if you can't do #1, you have to copy the map element by element to a new map, converting each element to the new type. An idiomatic way to do this is `std::transform`. You pass it the input container, the output container, and a function to transform each element:

   ```cpp
   std::map<uint64_t, std::u16string> input = /* ... */;
   std::map<uint16_t, std::string> output;

   std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<char16_t>, char16_t> converter;
   std::transform(
     input.begin(), 
     input.end(), 
     std::inserter(output, output.end()), 
     [&converter](auto& p) {
       return std::make_pair(
         static_cast<uint16_t>(p.first), // you probably want to check this
         converter.to_bytes(p.second));
     });
   ```

   personally, sometimes I find the stuff in `<algorithm>` hard to read. there's also nothing wrong with doing a manual loop:

   ```cpp
   std::map<uint64_t, std::u16string> input = /* ... */;
   std::map<uint16_t, std::string> output;

   std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<char16_t>, char16_t> converter;
   for (auto& p : input) {
     output.emplace(
       static_cast<uint16_t>(p.first), // you probably want to check this 
       converter.to_bytes(p.second));
   }
   ```

FYI, `<codecvt>` is now deprecated as of C++17 and it will likely be removed in a later standard. You might want to consider one of the many libraries out there to do encoding conversions instead of the standard one (as odd as that advice sounds).

Comment: You don't need to `make_pair`, you can `output.emplace` instead

Comment: good tip, thanks